# Why r.to.vect process takes too much time with topology analysis?

Tags: grass-gis, vectorization, land-use

My task is to vectorize a  standard landuse map (PROBA-V discrete classification) for extent 118.747182 54.231218 124.946218 60.060467 degrees. Raster is too detailed for me, so I generalize it.

I use:

```
r.neighbors input=landuse output=landuse_filt method=mode size=3 --overwrite
r.to.vect -sv input=landuse_filt output=landusemap type=area --overwrite
```

But even after generalizing, vectorizing takes hours to perform. It seems to me too time-comsuming. Adding -b flag makes the process go much quicker, but resulting file can't be opened.

What could be causes of this? May be, somebody has an experience to vectorize such landuse data, how did you managed?
PS It stucks on "Ättaching islands..." - Other previous work is done in a few minutes.

UPD: Yes, you are probably right, Micha, about millions of polygons (see attached 0.5 degree square of resulting landuse map).

[image: 0.5 degree square of resulting landuse map]

I should increase the window from 3 to 18 I think, also I will add a -c flag to make the window smoother, that would be more consistent with landuse data I think.

Comment: It could be that even after downscaling with r.neighbors, you're still creating a vector layer with millions of tiny polygons. Can you test first on a small subregion to see what the results look like?

Comment: I read that sometimes we need several iterations of r.neighbors process to reach the goal.
It has calculated (I let him do it yesterday as long time as it wanted), so now I have this map, which is rendering to Grass GUI for a very long time. When it is rendered, I could show the result. For now it seems you are right, I should test on very small region (however my current watershed is not too big - 210000 km2).

Comment: Do you use GRASS GIS 7 or 8?

Comment: Markus, I use 7.8.7